# Free HeatMap Layer Generator JavaScript Library

Tags: gratis, open-source, javascript, html

I have some customized maps, on those maps I want to place heat-map layers. My requirements are:

- A library for JavaScript
- Free for both personal and commercial use

I've found many libraries like heatmap.js, hotmaps.js but those are all licensed for free for only personal use.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what the map's look like, what format they are in, and what you want the end result to look like?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/mourner/simpleheat

Comment: Hi @Tom I've images like floor map blueprint. i want to place heat-map layer on image